# How to add Customized View in UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I have created a View containing labels and buttons with Controller.
By using addSubView method my view appears but button does not respond to view controller.. Can anybody help me doing what I want to do??

I have used this code to add view as subview in my alert view.

```
[myAlertView addSubview:myViewController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add an action on your button like below.**

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (IBAction) myAction
{
   //Action to perform when yourButton pressed.
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

```
    myview=[[UIView alloc] init];
    [myview setFrame:CGRectMake( 50.0f, 50.0f, 120.0f, 120.0f)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateTableView" context:nil];

     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
    [myview setFrame:CGRectMake( 90.0f, 20.0f, 280.0f, 170.0f)];

    myview.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    //myview.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 250);
    [self.view addSubview:myview];
    UIColor *forBackground = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple_bg.png"]];
    [myview setBackgroundColor:forBackground];
    myview.layer.cornerRadius=20;
    myview.clipsToBounds=YES;
    myview.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    myview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

    UITextView *mytext = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 10.0, 160.0, 25.0)];
    mytext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mytext.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    mytext.editable = NO;
    mytext.scrollEnabled=NO;
    mytext.scrollEnabled=NO;
    mytext.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    mytext.text = @"First label";
    [mytext release];
    [myview addSubview:mytext];

    entered = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0, 15.0, 150.0, 25.0)]; 
    [entered setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
    entered.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    entered.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    entered.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [entered addTarget:self action:@selector(textDidChange:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [myview addSubview:entered];

    UITextView *mytext2 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 50.0, 160.0, 25.0)];
    mytext2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mytext2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    mytext2.editable = NO;
    mytext2.scrollEnabled=NO;
    mytext2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    mytext2.text = @"Second label";
    [myview addSubview:mytext2];
    [mytext2 release];

    entered1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0, 55.0, 150.0, 25.0)]; 
    [entered1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    entered1.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    entered1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    entered1.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [myview addSubview:entered1];
    [entered1 release];

    UITextView *mytext3 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 90.0, 160.0, 25.0)];
    mytext3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mytext3.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    mytext3.editable = NO;
    mytext3.scrollEnabled=NO;
    mytext3.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    mytext3.text = @"Third Label";
    [myview addSubview:mytext3];
    [mytext3 release];

    entered2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0, 95.0, 150.0, 25.0)]; 
    [entered2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
    entered2.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    entered2.clipsToBounds = YES;
    entered2.text=@"Active";
    entered2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [myview addSubview:entered2];
    [entered2 release];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(EditTable:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(60.0, 130, 60, 30);
    [myview addSubview:button];

    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(EditTable1:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 130, 60, 30);
    [myview addSubview:button1];
    [self.view addSubview: myview];
```